# Round to x decimal place using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to round value with 5 decimal place.

I've tried `Math.round(x * 10000) / 10000` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)

Comment: If you are rounding to 5 places, you might want to multiply and divide by something with 5 zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code for more precious rounding, generally we use these to calculate insurance data:

```
BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(100);
decimal.round(new BigDecimal(10000).setScale(5,BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
```

Be careful in choosing the ceiling option. Refer big-decimal for more options.